# Heroku Rails app error log interpretation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, heroku

I am trying to get my app onto heroku however I keep getting errors. I was told to look into the logs to see what the problem is.
Would anyone be able to tell me the errors by looking at the logs ?

```
2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    2012-12-22T14:30:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2012-12-22T14:30:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2012-12-22T14:30:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2012-12-22T14:31:25+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by muhammedibhikha@gmail.com
    2012-12-22T14:31:30+00:00 heroku[run.8199]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2012-12-22T14:31:30+00:00 heroku[run.8199]: Awaiting client
    2012-12-22T14:31:31+00:00 heroku[run.8199]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-12-22T14:31:38+00:00 heroku[run.8199]: Process exited with status 1
    2012-12-22T14:31:38+00:00 heroku[run.8199]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-12-22T14:32:40+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by muhammedibhikha@gmail.com
    2012-12-22T14:32:40+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 18ea6ba by muhammedibhikha@gmail.com
    2012-12-22T14:32:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2012-12-22T14:32:43+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 25643`
    2012-12-22T14:32:49+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2012-12-22T14:32:49+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:25643
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by muhammedibhikha@gmail.com
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ^
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/franchise_application_controller.rb:45: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/controllers/franchise_application_controller.rb:45: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/app/controllers/franchise_application_controller.rb:45: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) (SyntaxError)
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     @inv_list = ['£25,000 to £50,000','£50,000...
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `require'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    2012-12-22T14:32:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2012-12-22T14:32:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2012-12-22T14:32:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2012-12-22T14:32:58+00:00 heroku[run.1220]: Awaiting client
    2012-12-22T14:32:58+00:00 heroku[run.1220]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2012-12-22T14:32:58+00:00 heroku[run.1220]: State changed from starting to up
    2012-12-22T14:33:06+00:00 heroku[run.1220]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
    2012-12-22T14:33:07+00:00 heroku[run.1220]: Process exited with status 0
    2012-12-22T14:33:07+00:00 heroku[run.1220]: State changed from up to complete
    2012-12-22T14:33:13+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:14+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:14+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:15+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:15+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:15+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:17+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:17+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:18+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2012-12-22T14:33:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=sleepy-cliffs-9120.herokuapp.com fwd=81.109.219.34 dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the `£` characters in `@inv_list = ['£25,000 to £50,000','£50,000...` in the `franchise_application_controller`. Try to include the following line at the very top of the file:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

The give away is "invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) " in the log and it's usually resolved with the encoding line.